# How is the Laplacian used for Unsharp Mask?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Matlab's *fspecial* unsharp mask uses a Laplacian kernel to achieve sharpening of the image.

From what I know, the image needs to be blurred first, and then the blurred image is subtracted from the original to get a sharper image. The Laplacian part comes exactly where alleged smoothing should take place. Correct me if I'm wrong, but Laplacian doesn't do any smoothing.

So how does the Laplacian help in sharpening the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is taken from: http://www.imagemet.com/WebHelp/spip.htm#hid_filters_edge_enhancement.htm

It explains quite well the Laplacian filter ;)

> The Laplacian filter separates itself from the other edge enhancement
>   filters because it uses second derivative information about the
>   intensity changes in an image through a difference equation.
>
> What is happening is that the difference of the center pixel is taken
>   with every surrounding pixel, and then averaged. At edges this
>   differential will be large and elsewhere it will be small, leaving
>   highlights only in the areas where sharp differentials, or edges,
>   occur. In the discrete domain the simplest approximation to the
>   continuous Laplacian is to compute the difference of slopes along each
>   axis.
>
> [image]
>
> The Laplacian operator can be defined in a two-dimensional plane as:
>
> 2D(x,y) = ¶ 2 I (x,y) / ¶ 2 x + ¶ 2 I (x,y) / ¶ 2 y
>
> In the discrete case it is approximated by the 4 connected grid as:
>
> L(x,y)= -I(x-1,y) -I(x+1,y) -I(x,y-1) -I(x,y+1) +4I(x,y)
>
> This four-neighborhood Laplacian can be generated the following
>   kernel:
>
> [image: images\ebx_-1416619947.gif]

Comment: it is very clear. but why adding a rows/cols of 0 before and after the derivate?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to sharpen an image.

One method is subtracting a blurred version of the image from the original.  This is known as [unsharp masking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsharp_masking).  This is the method that you described.

Using a Laplacian is a completely different approach.  The Laplacian is used to accentuate edges.  Smash has described its inner workings rather well, so I won't go into further details here.

Other methods include [deconvolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconvolution), [focus stacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_stacking) and [others](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/image-sharpening.htm).  There is considerable research in this area so if you're after more leading-edge approaches, have a look on Google Scholar.  The method one chooses to use generally depends on the problem and any related restrictions.